# Reading Data from Input Stream CLI - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am reading a book "Node.js in Action" and trying out examples from it. One of the example which creates a channel from "net" and then creates a channel for all connections and broadcasts messages to other connections/channels.

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');

var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subscriptions = {};

channel.on('join', function (id, client) {
    this.clients[id] = client;
    this.subscriptions[id] = function (senderId, message) {
        if (id !== senderId) {
            this.clients[id].write(message);
        }
    };
    this.on('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]);
});

channel.on('leave', function(id) {
  channel.removeListener('broadcast', this.subscriptions[id]);
  channel.emit('broadcast', id, id + " has left the chat. \n");
});

channel.on('shutdown', function() {
  channel.emit('broadcast', '', "Chat has shut down.!\n");
  channel.removeAllListeners('broadcast');
});

var server = net.createServer(function (client) {
    var id = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;
    //client.on('connect', function () {
    channel.emit('join', id, client);
    //});
    client.on('data', function (data) {
        data = data.toString();
        if(data == "shutdown\r\n") {
            channel.emit('shutdown');
        }
        channel.emit('broadcast', id, data);
    });
    client.on('close', function() {
      channel.emit('leave', id);
    });
});

server.listen(8888);
```

Now if you look at the following code:

```
client.on('data', function (data) {
    data = data.toString();
    if(data == "shutdown\r\n") {
        channel.emit('shutdown');
    }
    channel.emit('broadcast', id, data);
});
```

it reads data from command line when you connect to this server by using telnet using following command:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
```

and you can connect from multiple terminals/shells to this server running on localhost port 8888 but when it comes to reading input stream from telnet - it reads data as soon as user enters it. So if I want to detect a string "shutdown" with carriage return and line feed (\r\n) I am not able to do it because callback function gets called with each keystroke, so what you get is "s" "h" "u" "t" ... "n" as individual characters and not as a string buffer.

I read in APIs that there is flowing mode and pause mode but not sure how to implement it here.

There was another example in book where I encountered and I fixed it by comparing it with character-code and manually buffering till I encounter carriage-return key but I am looking forward to a better solution and preferably if node.js has something to offer.

```
var net = require('net');

var line = '';
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    if(data.toString().charCodeAt(0) != 13){
      line += data.toString();
    } else {
      //console.log('OO');
      socket.write(">>");
      socket.write(line);
      socket.write("\r\n");
      line = '';
    }
  });

  socket.once('data', function(data) {
    socket.write("Hey first time I always stay little reluctant..! Lolz!");
  })
});

server.listen(88);
```

Above code is the fix which I used for another example where I ran into similar problem but I want to know standard approach to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the original code and it works as expected on my mac.
As I suspected, your telnet client has `LINEMODE` disabled and is set to `character at a time`.

In `LINEMODE`, telnet sends what you type only on pressing enter but with it disabled, every keystroke is sent right away.

So, the issue has nothing to do with Node.js or your code but the telnet client.

You can use
`mode line`
and
`mode character` to switch between the two options.

Comment: on windows telnet client has only following option "set mode console" or "set mode stream" - none of them works.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb491013.aspx

tried with "SET crlf " as well but no luck.

Comment: Can you try `set crlf` ?

Comment: Yes I did `set crlf` but no luck.!

Looks like windows default telnet client has this problem, I tried with putty and it works like a charm but not sure how to make windows default client make it work. Same result whether I use command-line or powershell but putty works.! :)

Comment: Sadly, I do not have a windows machine atm so this is as far as I can help.

Comment: Thanks Rahat, it was some help for sure.